# Extract distinct values from yaml

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, yaml, python-2.x

I need to extract `--my_dataset`, `--my_table` and `--s3_temp_path` from below file using python script.

My File:

```yaml
▶ cat my_datasets/my_file.yml
__global__:
  role: myrole
  contact: sam@user.com

__default__:
  cc_policy: VERY_NEW
  act_num: 16384
  react_num: 16384
  with_start: 1
  where_to: my_file.log
  class: myClass
  my_arguements: >-
    -Dmy.num.1=4096
    -Dmy.num.2=true
    -Dmy.num.3=fgcd
  is_it: true
  if_not: false
  compure: dc1
  env: test
  my_compute: res-dc
  config: /my/file/config

first_adhoc:
  my_space: my_transfer
  doodle: my_transfer.tar.gz
  jar: my_transfer.jar
  my_dir: "dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/dir6/dir7/dir8/dir9/dir10/dir11:my-deploy"
  my_arguments: >-
    m.big.class
    --sdrs
    --tz UTC
    --env test
    --my_dataset my_analytics
    --my_table onboarding_client_events
    --current_date 2020-09-22
    --my_project my_aws_project
    --s3_temp_path s3://test-wierd/
    --my_key_json dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/keys.json
    --my_auth_file dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/gcp/my_new.yml
    --my_proxy example.com:9999
    --write_mode write
    --update_option option1 option2

first_cron:
  my_space: my_transfer
  doodle: my_transfer.tar.gz
  jar: my_transfer.jar
  my_dir: "dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/dir6/dir7/dir8/dir9/dir10/dir11:my-deploy"
  my_arguments: >-
    m.big.class
    --sdrs
    --tz UTC
    --env test
    --my_dataset my_analytics
    --my_table i_wish
    --current_date 2020-09-22
    --my_project my_aws_project
    --s3_temp_path s3://test-wierd/
    --my_key_json dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/keys.json
    --my_auth_file dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/gcp/my_new.yml
    --my_proxy example.com:9999
    --write_mode write
    --update_option option1 option2
  cron_schedule: "* * 4 * *"
```

I have a lot of files like the one that I mentioned above in the base_path, from all the files I need to get `--my_dataset`, `--my_table` and `--s3_temp_path`.

Below is how much longer I got so far. I was able to extract all the files with my_file.yaml recursively but I am not able to extract above mentioned *distinct* values.

My script:

```
import fnmatch
import os
import re
import yaml


user_path = os.path.expanduser('~')
source_path = user_path + "/where/are/"
base_path = source_path + "/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/dir6/dir7/dir8/dir9/dir10"


def find(pattern, base_path):
    results = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(base_path):
        for name in files:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, pattern):
                results.append(os.path.join(root, name))

    for result in results:
        stream = open(result, 'r')
        dictionary = yaml.load(stream)
        for key, value in dictionary.items():
            res = dict((k, dictionary[k]) for k in ['my_dataset', 'my_table', 's3_temp_path' ] 
                                        if k in dictionary) 
            print (key + " : " + str(value))

print find('my_file.yml', base_path)
```

Current result:

```
▶ python myWork.py
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
None
```

Expected results:

```
{"my_dataset": "my_analytics", "my_table": "i_wish", "s3_temp_path": "s3://test-wierd/"}
```

Comment: as you can see the keys you require are not present at the root level of the dictionary. They are present inside `my_arguments` which is inside another key itself. And is it `my_arguments` or `my_arguements` ?.

Comment: I am trying to extract in ```my_arguments```

Comment: you're not doing that in your code.

Comment: if I do this I still get an empty dictionary 

``` res = dict((k, dictionary[k]) for k in ['arguments'] 
                                        if k in dictionary) 
            # print (key + " : " + str(value))
            print res
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes the impression that you just wrote some random lines without thinking about the structure you try to navigate at all.

First, let's look at where your values are: They are contained in *one long folded scalar*. This will be loaded to a string in Python, you cannot directly query the values via their names, because YAML doesn't comprehend that those are cmdline params. So, let's write a function that extracts a value from this string:

```py
def get_cmdline_arg(name, cmdline):
  found = False
  for item in cmdline.split():
    if found: return item
    # if the current item is the searched name, the next item will be
    # its value
    found = (item == name)
  return "<not found>"
```

Now having that, let's look how to get the `my_arguments` string from the structure. Your YAML has four keys on its root level: `__global__`, `__default__`, `first_adhoc` and `first_cron`. The data you're searching is in `first_adhoc` and `first_cron`, so let's start by iterating those two values (starting with the loaded `dictionary` value from your code):

```py
for k in ['first_adhoc', 'first_cron']:
  arguments = dictionary[k]['my_arguments']
```

Now we have the `my_arguments` value, we just need to get your argument values:

```py
  res = {}
  for name in ['my_dataset', 'my_table', 's3_temp_path']:
    res[name] = get_cmdline_arg('--' + name, arguments)
  print(k + ": " + str(res))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply, I was able to resolve this by writing the below code.

```
import os
import yaml
tbl = []
def getNames(pattern, base_path):
    rsls = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(base_path):
        for name in files:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, pattern):
                rsls.append(os.path.join(root, name))
    for rsl in rsls:
        stream = open(rsl, 'r')
        dictionary = yaml.load(stream)
        for key, value in dictionary.items():
            if 'my_arguments' in value:
                arg_val = value['my_arguments']
                tname_fractions = []
                for col in col_names:
                    col_val = arg_val.split(col)[1].strip().split()[0]
                    tname_fractions.append(col_val)
                tbl_nm = ','.join(tname_fractions)
                tbls.append(tbl_nm)
                utl = list(set(tbls))

    return utl
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I agree with your point that I didn't put much thought into it. I just started learning Python.